# How to set active downloads in session with libtorrent/Python

Tags: python-3.x, ubuntu, download, settings, libtorrent

I'm trying to made a script to download files in python. So far so good with the default settings for the session. but when i'm trying to set 'active downloads' it just doesn't download. I'm sure i'm doing it wrong but i dont know where. The default for active downloads in libtorrent is 3. How am I suposse to change session settings? I'm really newbie in python.

Heres the code:

```
import libtorrent as lt
sett = lt.session_settings()
sett = {'allow_multiple_connections_per_ip': True,
  'active_downloads': -1,
  'active_checking': -1,
  'active_seeds': 7,
  'active_limit': -1}

ses = lt.session()
ses.listen_on(6881, 6891)
ses.set_settings(sett)
downloads = []
```

Here's where i suposse to put the torrent. The documentation says that I have to set auto_managed to false in order to change the active downloads.

```
source = 'downloads/torrents/'
params = {
    "save_path": "/download/",
    "ti": lt.torrent_info(list(source.keys())[0]),
    'auto_managed': False,
}
downloads.append(ses.add_torrent(params))
```

and here the code is executed.

```
import time
from IPython.display import display
import ipywidgets as widgets

state_str = [
    "queued",
    "checking",
    "downloading metadata",
    "downloading",
    "finished",
    "seeding",
    "allocating",
    "checking fastresume",
]

layout = widgets.Layout(width="auto")
style = {"description_width": "initial"}
download_bars = [
    widgets.FloatSlider(
        step=0.01, disabled=True, layout=layout, style=style
    )
    for _ in downloads
]
display(*download_bars)

while downloads:
    next_shift = 0
    for index, download in enumerate(downloads[:]):
        bar = download_bars[index + next_shift]
        if not download.is_seed():
            s = download.status()

            bar.description = " ".join(
                [
                    download.name(),
                    str(s.download_rate / 1000),
                    "kB/s down,",
                    str(s.upload_rate / 1000),
                    "kB/s Up,",                 
                    str(s.num_peers),
                    "Peers",
                    state_str[s.state],
                ]
            )
            bar.value = s.progress * 100

        else:
            next_shift -= 1
            ses.remove_torrent(download)
            downloads.remove(download)
            bar.close()
            download_bars.remove(bar)
            print(download.name(), "done")
        time.sleep(5)
```

It was working great Before I tried to change settings in the first part and changing auto_managed.
So i supposse maybe that's not the way. I've readt like all the documentation but I dont know how to apply it. can someone help me?

*I'm sorry for my bad englisg*

Comment: just to be clear, what you're trying to do is to set the libtorrent `active_downloads` configuration. The one documented here https://libtorrent.org/reference-Settings.html#active_limit is that right?

Comment: Yeah. That's true. I actually could find a way already. I put it in other comment. The documentation is really big.

Answer (score 0):

the torrent limit settings, as the [documentation](https://libtorrent.org/reference-Settings.html#active_limit) states, *only* apply to torrents that are "auto managed". setting `auto_managed` to false for a torrent, is a way to opt-out of the automatic start/stop/queue logic built-into libtorrent. By default it's true and by default libtorrent will limit the number of simultaneous downloading torrents.

Comment: Thanks for clarying. Yeah. I was a bit confused about it and i didn't need to set it. Thanks. So far working great. Such a lovely code.

Answer (score 0):

So here's how the session should beggin in order to download multiple torrents. Set the session, set the settings and aply those settings to sessions.

```
ses = lt.session()
ses.listen_on(6881, 6891)
sett = lt.session_settings()
sett = {'allow_multiple_connections_per_ip': True,
  'dont_count_slow_torrents': True,
  'active_downloads': -1,
  'active_seeds': 7,
  'active_checking': 3,}

ses.set_settings(sett)

downloads = []
```

And yeah. auto_managed didn't need to be set as False. Thanks for the help-.